# Codeigniter/PHP: How to merge distinct arrays and make it unique into one array in query result

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

[image: ingredient]  **- ingredient**

[image: menu] - **menu**
[image] **recipe**

[image: console]

How will I merge the two array under **name** into one array and make it unique. As you can see the result on the [0] is

> Beef Adobo
>
> qwerty
>
> iswi

and on [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMV2N.png) is

> qwerty
>
> iswi

I want the both of them to be in one array and the result should be

> Beef Adobo
>
> qwerty
>
> iswi

**query:**

```
public function get_halal($name) {

    $terms = explode(',', $name);

    foreach ($terms as $name) {
        $this->db->distinct();
        $this->db->select('r_name');

        $this->db->from('recipe');

        $this->db->join('menu', 'menu.recipe_id = recipe.recipe_id');
        $this->db->join('ingredient', 'ingredient.ingredient_id = menu.ingredient_id');
        $this->db->where('menu.category_id = 2');
        $this->db->like('ingredient.name', $name);

        $query = $this->db->get()->result();

        $data[] = $query;
    }
    return $data;
}
```

**controller:**

```
public function ajaxSearchHalal() {
    postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");

    if (isset($postdata)) {
        $post = json_decode($postdata);

        $name = $post->name;


        if ($this->user_model->get_halal($name)) {
            $user_id = $this->user_model->get_halal($name);

            $data = array(
                'name' => $user_id,
            );

            echo json_encode($data);
        } else {
            echo json_encode("false");
        }


    } else {
        echo "Error!";
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the purpose of your `menu` table exactly?

Comment: Can you show an example of your `menu` table in the database?

Comment: The reason Im asking about the `menu` table is because you shouldn't have to worry about merging your result arrays. You just need to fix your query. Provide your tables with examples so that we can give you the best answer.

Comment: @CodeGodie the menu table is where i can get the category_id of my recipes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I see what you are doing now. Thanks for including your tables.

From what I see, you are trying to get all the recipe names, from the `recipe` table, that have the ingredients your are passing.

What you need to do to fix this issue is not worry about how to merge the arrays, but how you can redo your sql query in order to obtain the information you want in just one query. The way you have it now is not efficient as you are calling a query per every iteration.

What you need to do is use `WHERE IN`, and `GROUP BY` to get the info you need and group them by a column. Redo your model method like this:

```
public function get_halal($name) {

    $terms = explode(',', $name);

    $this->db->select("r.name");
    $this->db->from('recipe r');
    $this->db->join('menu m', 'm.recipe_id = r.recipe_id');
    $this->db->join('ingredient i', 'i.ingredient_id = m.ingredient_id');
    $this->db->where('m.category_id = 2');
    $this->db->where_in('i.name', $terms);
    $this->db->group_by('r.recipe_id');
    $q = $this->db->get();
    return $q->result();
}
```

This will give you one result set which you can then pass as `JSON` to your front-end without having to iterate or merge arrays.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sweet. No problem. Glad I was able to help.